# How to monitor CPU usage using a bash script and top over time?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I've been given the task to use top(htop is not an option on our system) to monitor CPU usage over time. If a user is on a server and using over 100% for longer than an hour, an email alert will be sent out to an admin.

Easily enough I written the code below to give me the information I need. You can see the code and results below. The issue I'm facing is I can't figure out how to go about running this script over time. How do I go about running this script once an hour and test if a user is continuing to use to much CPU%?

```
1 #!/bin/bash
2
3 echo "Script was run at $(date)" >> temp1
4
5 HOSTS=("list of server names")
6
7 for i in ${HOSTS[@]} ; do
8         echo $i >> temp1
9         ssh $i top -b -n 1 | tail -n +7 | awk '$9 >= 100.0' | awk '{print $2, $9, $12}' >> temp1
10 done
11
```

```
Currently this is what my script is returning, so far so good: 
serverName1
user 187.1 MATLAB
serverName2
user 144.4 plasma-de+
user 144.4 plasma-de+
user 141.7 plasma-de+
user 138.9 mate-sett+
serverName3
user 100.0 plasma-de+
user 100.0 plasma-de+
```

Comment: If you run it just once per hour, you'd warn a user who happens to have 100% CPU for just one second when you run the script, though. You'd have to run it continuously instead.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Ah good catch, will do it continuously instead. That's easy enough to figure out, but I'm still unsure on how I'd trigger the alert for extended use?

Comment: I would run a CRON every minute and store temp data in a database ..  Run comparisons with stored data and either "clear it" or "keep it" .. If kept for over 1 hour -- Send email to admin and "don't clear" ..  --  Seems a better use of resources for such a quick script, than a continuously running program/proccess

Comment: @Zak can you expand on the keep it/clear it process for me please? That's the main roadblock I was facing. Was just having a hard time breaking down that process. My first thought was appending the data to the same tempFile every time it runs and after that clearing any non duplicates. Main issue was figuring out how to determine if the same user was present in the file for over an hour.

Comment: If you used a database to do that -- You can compare [TIMESTAMPS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) --  I would create a `process_started` and a `process_updated` `TIMESTAMP` -- update the `process_ updated` every minute if CPU is 100%.  at the same time test to see if it's been an hour.  If the process dips to below 100, clear the entry out of the DB.  Any entries in for over 60 mins get emailed to admin.

Comment: @Zak Very helpful thank you. Just one more thing, as I'm running this on numerous hosts it's important to know where the user is. You can see above how the current top output looks. I want to append the servername to each line, but the top command outputs all processes at once. Any ideas for that? Currently I just echo the hostname before each top command, but if I'm pushing this to a database, it'd be better if it was inline.

Comment: Hostname inline? Replace `awk '{print $2, $9, $12}'` with `awk -v host="$a" '{print host, $2, $9, $12}'`.

Comment: Combine `awk '$9 >= 100.0' | awk '{print ...}' ` into `awk '$9 >= 100.0' {print ...}' `

Comment: There are a lot of monitoring tools, I can't tell what one is best in your situation.  With `top` option `-b` sounds interesting (keep top running on remote servers, writing results on the remote servers and fetch them periodically).

Comment: This seems more of a sysadmin kind of task and other comments are enumerating use of cron for periodicity and need to track a moving average. 

But, why re-invent the wheel when there are things like the opensource nagios core software?